# How Bootstrap modal get 'id' from url

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to get `'id'` from url and using in my Bootstrap modal.
How to get this `'69'`.In my modal i using this `'69'` with SQL request.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter

Comment: If you can, it's better to render a JavaScript variable, which will hold that ID, server-side. URL parsing will depend on URL format, so if you change it in a future, it can break your parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Hope, your JS code is somehow similar to it.

```
<script>
    $('.Contact').click(function(){
        var id=$('.Contact').val();
        $.ajax({url:"ModalPage.php?id="+id,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $(".modal-content").html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>
```

In, **ModalPage.php**

```
<?
$id=$_GET['id'];

  // Now, use this 'id'.
?>
```

Comment: No Man. I'm Delighted That This Answer Is Now Having Right Syntax. Thanku For Making Correction @HawasKaPujaari. I always have respect for you. Thanku for giving so much time to stack.

Comment: Indeed. We are a family here! ^_^ stay safe and keep coding ;-)

Answer (score 1):

an easy trick is to make hidden input inside modal code as below

```
<div id="myModal">
   <form>
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['id']?$_GET['id']:''); ?>" /> <!--if you want to make it hidden-->
     <label>ID = <?php echo isset($_GET['id']?$_GET['id']:''); ?></label><!--if you want to display-->
      <!--your code-->
   </form>
</div>
```